# Prevent people finding which IP address my android app is sending requests to

Tags: android, ip, server

I have an android application which makes requests to a server and shows the result to users. I know that there are ways that others can find which ip my app makes requests to (such as [online android app disassemble tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/undx/)). I mean when someone tries to disassemble my app then he/she can find such this line of code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my ip or url");
```

How can I prevent them from getting this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide it, but you cannot remove it totally unless you are using something like [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/).

Some example ways to hide your String

1. Store it as static variable byte[] and convert it to String upon use
2. XOR the url with some other fixed byte[]

Actually you can perform any operation to your String as long as the operation is reversible, i.e. you can recreate the required String from it.

It is actually the same as what you need to do to protect public key.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#key